# Bind DetailsView field to Function instead of Property

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, detailsview

Is it possible to display the result of a function instead of the value of a property in a DetailsView Field?

For example instead of:

```
<asp:Label ID="m_LabelPlantCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlantCode") %>'></asp:Label>
```

maybe something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="m_LabelPlantCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlantCode(true)") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Text='<%# ((YourObject) Container.DataItem).PlantCode(true) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to bind the result of a function to a field of DetailsView.

Instead of `<%# Bind("PlantCode(true)") %>`

you could use `<%# SomeFunc(Bind("PlantCode") %>`
and `SomeFunc` in this case would a server side method accepting args of type `PlantCode`.

Hope it helps!